# Child component not rerendering on change of props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Here is the parent component :

```
    state = {
    books: undefined
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    BooksAPI.getAll().then(books => {
      this.setState({books},this.filterBooks);
    });
  }

  filterBooks() {
    this.currentlyReading = this.state.books.filter((book) => book.shelf === 'currentlyReading');
    this.read = this.state.filter((book) => book.shelf === 'read');
    this.wantToRead = this.state.filter((book) => book.shelf === 'wantToRead');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <Route path="/search" component={SearchBook} />
        <Route exact
          path="/"
          render={() => <BookScreen
            currentlyReading={this.currentlyReading}
            read={this.read}
            wantToRead={this.wantToRead}
          />} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

I expect that the props will change for `BookScreen` component after filterBooks is called and the component should rerender, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way for now, which still follows React's way is: after having `books` data, call 1 function only, and this function will process everything and update state after finishing (we pass the `books` object as parameter), like this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    BooksAPI.getAll().then(books => {
      this.filterBooks({books});
    });
  }

  filterBooks = (books) => {
    this.currentlyReading = books.filter((book) => book.shelf === 'currentlyReading');
    this.read = books.filter((book) => book.shelf === 'read');
    this.wantToRead = books.filter((book) => book.shelf === 'wantToRead');
    this.setState({ books: books });
  }
```

If you have any error, feel free to post here then we can get through together!

========

***Added explanation on why the author's original code doesn't work:***

Based on my little experience with React and JS:

When a new state is set, it may take time (maybe 100-300ms, that is why you execute the original `this.filterBooks` using the syntax `this.setState({books},this.filterBooks)`

=> This seems to be right, which means after a new state of `books` is already set, you can access it the `filterBooks` function.)

HOWEVER: after new state of `books` is set, the page will be re-rendered, and `filterBooks` will be executed (perhaps at the same time => not sure which one ends first, so let's say for example, `this.currentlyReading` is still undefined in `render()` if `render()` happens first, before the result of `filterBooks` is completely set!

In other words, React is Javascript, and Javascript's asynchronization is troublesome!

Comment: Yeah this would definitely work and surely follows react style but I am unable to understand why isn't the component rerendering when the props are changing. Thanks for suggesting the valuable approach.

Comment: Based on my little experience with React and JS: when a new state is set, it may take time (maybe 100-300ms, that is why you execute the original [this.filterBooks] using the syntax [this.setState({books},this.filterBooks)] => this seems to be right, which means after a new state of "books" is already set, you can access it the "filterBooks" function.) HOWEVER: after new state of "books" is set, the page will be re-rendered, and "filterBooks" will be executed (at the same time => not sure which one ends first, so for example, "this.currentlyReading" is undefined in render()

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do this, Just update the books state like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  BooksAPI.getAll().then(books => this.setState({books}));
}
```

This will cause a **re-render**. But since you're not using the state directly to populate your child component, we need to call the `filterBooks()` inside the `render()` method.

```
render() {
   this.filterBooks()
return (
  <div className="app">
    <Route path="/search" component={SearchBook} />
    <Route exact
      path="/"
      render={() => <BookScreen
        currentlyReading={this.currentlyReading}
        read={this.read}
        wantToRead={this.wantToRead}
      />} />
  </div>
  )
}
```

The call to that method will update the data that you pass as props to your child component.

Comment: we can pass callback to `setState` which gets called when the state has been changed. I don't think that should be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I realize that `this.filterBooks()' should ideally be called inside `render()` method since preparing props for child component should be the part of rendering logic of parent component. This would allow the code to gracefully evolve.